# Stored procedure throws Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint when called concurrently with same parameters

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    SomeText varchar(10) NOT NULL
)  ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable 
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_SomeTable 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID)
         WITH(STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
              ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertSomeText]
    @ID int,
    @SomeText varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DELETE FROM SomeTable WHERE ID = @ID

    INSERT INTO SomeTable (ID, SomeText)
    VALUES (@ID, @SomeText)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION      
END
```

The above stored procedure sometimes throws an error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

when called at the same time with the same `@ID` value.

Delete / Insert operation are inside a transaction so I think it would be an atomic operation, but still some time it throws the exception.

Comment: It doesn't matter than the procedure is inside a transaction. If they both start at the same time, they are both effectively just trying to insert the same ID.

Comment: This maybe a dumb question, since I assume this is a simplified version, but why delete and then insert when you can simply update?

Comment: ...or a `MERGE` statement?

Comment: yes, it's a merge statement, about 5 years ago when we developed that software merge statement was not recommended .

Comment: You [should still use `MERGE` with caution](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/), many of the bugs still exist, but they are in my opinion, mostly edge cases, and for a simple upsert on a table it *should* be fine. You should still test it behaves as expected before releasing anything to production though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually very few fool proof methods of avoiding a race condition, using transactions is not one of them unless you specify locking level. Unfortunately I have never seen the upsert managed with a delete and insert, so I can't find any documentation or testing to show how and why the race conditions occurs.

Rather than fix a somewhat bizarre method (delete/insert), I'd suggest simply using [`MERGE WITH (HOLDLOCK)`](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx), which is thread safe:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertSomeText]
    @ID int,
    @SomeText varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE dbo.SomeTable WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS t
    USING (VALUES (@ID, @SomeText)) s (ID, SomeText)
        ON s.ID = t.ID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET SomeText = s.SomeText
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT (ID, SomeText) VALUES (s.ID, s.SomeText);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing ISOLATION LEVEL to SERIALIZABLE  (most restrictive) to avoid any concurrency issue. 
For details refer MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173763.aspx